# Is there an age requirement to play in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, social, teenagers

The people in my local D&D Adventurers League are all grown men who say I am too young to join, even though I am 13.

Is that true? Is there a minimum age to play in AL games?

Comment: There's some ambiguity. Is this an officially sanctioned AL event? -- If I follow the AL rules I could play an AL game in my own home and have my own rules about who can play. You say "local D&D" but I suppose I could technically host it in a public space but it still be "my event" with my own rules (if that makes sense).

Comment: If your parents have not already gone to bat for you on this matter, how do you think that a bunch of strangers on the internet can help you?  Have your parents tried to intercede on your behalf yet?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Adventurers League is not supposed to have a minimum age requirement. When I was playing at local AL tables, one of the regulars was a 10-year old with autism and ADHD, and when he was focused he was good. When he couldn't focus we sent him on errands, which he was glad to do anyway because he'd been sitting still longer than he could really manage. The DM took over his character for a little bit while he ran a couple blocks to get sodas or whatever. Win-win.

The players may be trying to shoo you away because they've tried integrating younger players and had it go badly. Find out in what way it went badly and resolve not to be the kind of player that creates those problems. The DM is within their rights to ask you to leave if you are disruptive, so know your character's abilities and spells and so on and be a helpful part of the team.

With that said, having an official AL table means they can't actually turn you away without risking their AL status. They shouldn't be turning people away for reasons like that, only for cheating or repeated super-disruptive behavior. I've only seen one person ejected from a table and that was for threatening violence against another player.

Assuming your AL game is at a local gaming store, the official AL organizer is probably the store owner or manager, and might also be the DM but probably isn't aware the players or the DM are discouraging you from participating. Talk to them and let them gently remind the DM and others that this space is supposed to be for you too. While the players may have turned it into a private club for themselves, they are kind of misusing what they've been given. If they want a private club and they're grown men, they can pool their money for a folding table and play a home game in someone's basement.

According to their [FAQ](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/DDAL_FAQv6-1.pdf) there doesn't seem to be any requirement for players other than having a DCI number. The only requirement to [register a DCI number](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/new-wizards-account-system) is to either be 13+ or have a parent/legal guardian's consent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93536/discussion-on-answer-by-jamesb-is-there-an-age-requirement-to-play-in-adventurer).

Comment: The third paragraph is completely wrong. It implies the existence of some sort of official body to regulate "AL status". No such body exists.

Comment: I think if someone started contacting any of the [AL campaign staff](http://dndadventurersleague.org/contact-us/campaign-staff/), especially Lysa or Amy, with complaints of discrimination and abusive treatment, the FLGS hosting these AL games would find their [events](https://dndadventurersleague.org/start-here/stores/) removed from the Store and Event locator on the AL site, and probably start getting letters from lawyers informing them they were being removed from the [Wizards Play Network](https://wpn.wizards.com/en/join-wpn).

Answer (score 0):

No, but GMs basically have the right to kick you out of the group if you are acting in a disruptive fashion. As a 13 year old, your brain hasn’t finished developing yet, and it’s entirely possible that you might act in a socially disruptive fashion without realising it or intending to, simply because the portion of the brain responsible for impulse control hasn’t fully developed in kids your age.

Additionally, depending on your location, there may be regulatory requirements for staff and volunteers that interact with children, like the Australian government’s requirement for Working With Children Checks and their associated state-level ID cards. If the event was intended for adults, it’s possible that the staff haven’t had these checks done. As a result, it’s entirely possible that it may not be legal for you to remain at the store without the presence of at least one of your parents or legal guardians.

Comment: In our current legalese environment, the second paragraph here is a key issue that is an unfortunate side effect of how liability-conscious people have become.  I think you ought to consider adding to the first paragraph that adults are allowed to, and expected to, do risk assessment for their group.  That appears to be the core point you are making in paragraph one.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I was referring to the Adventurer's League rules, which allow a GM to remove a disruptive player from their table.

Comment: I get that, but since the person asking this question has yet to play with them, and has yet to be disruptive or not, that's an odd fit for an answer.

Comment: I would upvote this answer, were it only the second paragraph. I know quite a few kids who are fully capable of playing D&D at a table with adults (and others who aren't). The first paragraph is to broadly sweeping for my taste.